# my Mathematica has turned orange and not able to find out why

Tags: notebooks

I do not know what happened. But when I rebooted my PC, now Mathematica comes up orange colored. I shut down the PC and tried again, it is still orange. Here is screen shot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also did a reset. Holding down the ctrl-shift key. And it is still orange colored

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also deleted `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica` and started, and it is still orange.

All pop-ups and help now is also orange

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also the little `+` thing on the start of the cell is orange:

[image]

I am not expecting someone to just know the cause of this, but may be someone else had this problem and can suggest what to do.

Windows 7 did large update on my PC last night, so it might have something to do with it, not sure. Here is the list of the updates

[image]

I did not do anything to Mathematica itself or change anything configuration with it. I just turned orange. No other app I am using has turned orange as well.

specs: Version 10.1, 64 bits, windows 7, 64 bits.

---

**Update**

I found something interesting: When I take image of the cell using SEUploader, then it comes up in the image with orange background. While in the notebook itself, it is still white. So SEPloader is picking up the orange color from somewhere. Here is screen shot:

[image]

Maybe the above will give a clue to the problem.

per request below, here is the color setting on my PC. I never touch this stuff as I do not understand colors.

[image]

But I turned the option above to "use NVIDIA setting" from the "Other applications control color settings" and restarted Mathematica, and it is still orange.

Added result of

```
FileNames["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Data\\ICC\\*"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is it just me or do the desktop icons in the background of the first picture look orange as well?  That reminds me of what it looked like when a CRT monitor I had was dying.  Yuck.  I hope your problem is fixed soon.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, the monitor is fine. I have 2 monitors, new, and they all bright and working fine. Mathematica remain orange on both monitors. All my others apps are not orange.  Well, it is not a huge problem for now, as the notebook interface has the white background still. So I can live with it. But thought to check in case it is a know issue or someone can suggest something.

Comment: Hey guys you must be kidding, Nasser is showing a **screendump**. Any problems with a CRT or a plug would not show in a digital image.

Comment: My impression is that there is something with the color temperature. It looks like there is some problem with the color profile that is being used.

Comment: @Sjoerd Not kidding but *also* not implying it's an actual monitor problem; just that I remember how icky that is to work under!  However I think you might be on to something; maybe the some weird display profile is being loaded?  How might this be related to *Mathematica*?

Comment: @nasser Could you examine the Color Management control panel to see whether you see something unusual?

Comment: The display driver updates certainly seem relevant; try rolling them back.

Comment: @ilian well, ok, but I am afraid to break something, it is only Mathematica which turned orange after the windows update. But if there is no other solution, then will try to do this later on. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate `FileNames["C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.1\\SystemFiles\\Data\\ICC\\*"]` ?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries added result to my question.

Comment: You added the NVidia control panel, but that is not the Color Management control panel I was talking about. That is a standard Windows control panel.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I just did. I run the control panel->Calibrate color-> and clicked next to all options (did not actually change anything) and then clicked apply. Then I restarted Mathematica. And now the color orange has gone ! and it is now turned back to the way it was. If you like to post this as an answer, so I can accept it. This might be useful if it happens to someone in the future.

Comment: Actually I don't believe I really gave an answer, just some clues to look at. BTW did you mean the "Calibrate display" button in the [Color Management control panel](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj9ks.png)? I don't have a "Calibrate color" control panel.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries added screen shot. It is under display->Calibrate color. If you can answer this, so I can accept and close this. Your hint made me try this.

Comment: OK I see. You have your control panel view setting on categories. You can see the Color Management control panel only if you have selected the icons option. I believe the calibration option in both panels to do similar things in the end.

Comment: Hmm, this made me think of the f.lux app to aid sleep ... http://nerdsmagazine.com/apps-like-flux-for-android/ by reducing the blue component of radiated light from your display. Is this an undocumented feature in MMA? :)

Comment: Nasser, you should put your solution section in a self-answer, or edit Sjoerd's answer to include it.  Keep the question clean and the example of the problem at the top.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In either the Display or the Color Management control panel navigate to the calibration option and change some settings and revert back. Click Apply to see if it helps.

---

*Pasted from question:*

Problem resolved. Thanks to suggestion by SjoerdC.deVries in comments. I run the windows color calibration and clicked apply, then restarted Mathematica, and now the orange color has gone:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It looks like the windows 7 monitor updates caused Mathematica to get little confused. Running windows `control panel->Calibrate color->Apply` fixed whatever the problem was. Here is the button to click on:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a very bizarre feature of M10.  I encountered the same issue with Windows 8 and recalibrating the display color did the trick.

Comment: So, now we have to find out under which circumstances it happens (I have not encountered this yet).

Comment: ...and after using this solution, my Mathematica (10.0.2) suddenly needs extra time "Formatting Notebook Contents".  A very bizarre bug indeed.

Comment: Are you sure it's related? Many people get this message (myself included) though we haven't changed this setting or suffer from the orange bug.

Comment: I won't go so far as to say I'm certain; however I didn't have the problem beforehand, calibrated the color via the control panel, observed the "formatting notebook contents issue" and had my white background returned.

Comment: @bobthechemist without a doubt, *Mathematica* (even version 9, which takes a long time to start) has some odd problems with monitors on Windows 7 and 8. I managed to fix my laptop using the monitor driver replacement suggested elsewhere, but for my multiple-monitor desktop, it made no difference. The same problems are not observed on Windows 2003. Someone surely needs to have a serious look at what the FE is doing here. (Hoping for the best with 10.2!) Thanks to your comment, in the mean time, I will try uncalibrating my color and see if it helps.

Comment: @bobthechemist it worked! Unfortunately, it had the side effect of turning **my** *Mathematica* orange as well...

Comment: @OleksandrR. This is actually quite comical (on second thoughts, make it tragicomical)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I set the sRGB color profile that comes with *Mathematica* as the default. My colors look rather washed out, but at least *Mathematica* starts quickly and without the annoying "Formatting notebook contents" messages. And without being orange! So, thanks for your hint that *Mathematica* comes with ICC profiles.

Comment: @OleksandrR. To be sure: You set the color profile using the Windows Color Management control panel to the SystemFiles\\Data\\ICC files I mentioned above, or did you do something from within Mathematica?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, that's right. I tried some of Windows's built in ones as well but it did not succeed in removing the orange color. I wonder if *Mathematica*'s profile is faulty (i.e. causes the orange) but when the monitor and the application both have the faulty profile, this cancels out? Further experiments would be needed. It is interesting that *Mathematica* 9 also starts up much faster now.