# Suddenly mathematica is very slow when screen is calibrated on windows

Tags: installation

I installed V 10.0.2 64-bit when it was released. Since then it worked, except for the bugs. I used it earlier today, no problems. However this evening, opening Mathematica lasted a very long time of "formatting notebook contents". Creating a new document, opening document and everything that relates to "Mathematica.exe" is delayed at least 1-2 seconds.

I disabled the welcome screen which made it a bit better though.

I also have an old V 8.0.4.0, which exhibits the same behavior when I open the program, and shows the welcome screen. Opening/Saving etc is not affected in this version.

I tried restart, reinstall v10, and move the files stored in AppData/Roaming, and AppData/Local, but nothing changes.

After the reinstall, when I press "enter activation key" I firstly gets an error:
[image]
 then it opens a window saying "activation succeded", but the "enter activation key" thing is still in the menu.

Comment: I've had this happen a couple of times, and it was quite strange: startup took a ridiculous amount of time, once in, certain things (new nb, etc.) seemed to take longer. In both cases, strangely enough, it was updating the graphics driver that fixed the symptoms.

Comment: @ciao Actually right before the first time mathematica behaved crap, I follow the instructions from Control Panel -> Screen -> Calibrate Screen, where i set the gamma, and four times choose which text is more readable.

Comment: The comments below [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87076/57) may be relevant to you.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You made my day, I did this:
1. Control panel -> Color management -> Advanced -> Unmark the setting "Use windows screen calibration"
2. Press Modify system standards, select the screen device, and remove all apparent profiles that are attached to it.
Solved the problem

Comment: Good to hear that! It might be a good idea to self-answer this question with this information.