# Mathematica suddenly became extremly slow (Windows 10)

Tags: system-performance

I restarted my computer, and Mathematica became eeeextremly slow. It takes like 5mn to make calculations it used to do in 3seconds.

I have seen [Suddenly mathematica is very slow when screen is calibrated on windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88565/suddenly-mathematica-is-very-slow-when-screen-is-calibrated-on-windows) and I tried to do the same but I am with windows 10 and the title of the menu aren't exactly the same.

I went in the color management menu to try to disable "Use window screen calibration" (étalonnage in French). But the option is grey I cannot disable it.

Is there a way to fix this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Contact Wolfram Support, in my opinion. Support@wolfram.com

Comment: In the 'Advanced' tab of color management press the button 'Change system defaults' at the bottom. A new window opens. Go to its 'Advanced' tab, and disable 'Use window screen calibration' from there. Also in the 'Device' tab, remove all profiles associated with your screen device.