# Color degrades when using Copy As Bitmap

Tags: front-end, bugs, color, image, windows

I have discovered a problem that affects my use of *Mathematica*.  When I use the menu command **Edit** > **Copy As** > **Bitmap** the colors in the copy are subtly degraded.  To make this more apparent I copied and pasted repeatedly with the following result:

[image]

This is a major problem as I have been assuming that **Copy As** > **Bitmap** was a lossless operation.

Is there an explanation for this behavior?  Is there a better work-around than using <kbd>Print Scrn</kbd>, pasting, and cropping?  Which versions and platforms are affected?

I am using *Mathematica* 10.1 under Windows 7.

---

### *Update*

- Following both Oleksandr's comments Alexey's analysis I removed any profile associated with my monitor from the Windows **Color Management** dialog, and repeated the experiment (using Alexey's code).
- Now the last copy is visually identical to the original, confirming that this is a problem with how *Mathematica* handles monitor profiles.
- Notably the LUT for my calibration profile is still loaded into my graphics card (it was loaded at start-up by the utility **ColorVisionStartup**).  *This means that it is possible to have both calibration and verbatim copying in Mathematica; the problem entirely separate.*
- Un-associating the monitor profile in **Color Management** after the LUT is loaded is a viable work-around, but quite inconvenient and prone to error as one would need to remember to re-associate the profile before restarting Windows.

Comment: Probably one of the many problems with device color profiles in version 10. Have you tried applying *Mathematica*'s ICC profile to your monitor and seeing if the problem persists?

Comment: @Oleksandr I feel ignorant; I did not know that *Mathematica* had its own ICC profile.  Please tell me more or give me the appropriate documentation link.

Comment: I am not sure if it is documented, because color management certainly does not work properly (it is the cause of the slow startup and annoying "formatting notebook contents" messages experienced by many, and also Nasser's bizarre orange problem). Anyway, if you search within the installation directory for `*.icc`, you will find there are a couple of them in there. These also exist in version 9 and the same slow startup problem exists in that, but the implementation is sufficiently limited that there are no other observable issues until version 10 as far as I know.

Comment: This is probably the question OleksandrR. is referring to: [my-mathematica-has-turned-orange-and-not-able-to-find-out-why](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87072/my-mathematica-has-turned-orange-and-not-able-to-find-out-why)

Comment: On Windows Mathematica versions 8, 9 and 10 have exact the same problem.

Comment: Copying a bitmap just by ctrl-C ctrl-V seems to leave the bitmap unaltered though.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I cannot reproduce this in version 9 on Windows 2003. This is what makes me think it is due to color management (which is implemented much more simply on Windows versions before Vista; the same problem with slow startup also does not exist in XP/2003).

Comment: @Oleksandr I was not able to set the ICC profile as monitor colorspace because it is not recognized as a valid monitor profile.  However following your idea I set a different monitor profile and repeated the experiment.  This resulted in degradation in a *different* pattern than the one shown above indicating this is related if not directly causal.  Why would (or rather should) *Mathematica* be changing the data based on the monitor profile?  This feels like a bug to me but I need confirmation.

Comment: The sRGB profile should be valid for monitors (although the other one isn't; it's for printing onto coated paper). I agree that it is probably a bug. I think *Mathematica* transforms one way (either on copy or on paste; clearly it is on copy according to you, and seemingly also in the linked thread as the problem is visible in the SEUploader) but fails to apply the inverse transformation. The same problem is what I suppose leads to the orange color of the interface.

Comment: @Oleksandr Not all RGB profiles are recognized by Windows as valid monitor profiles; I believe the file must be `.icm` not `.icc` though I have not explored it further.  Why should *Mathematica* be transforming on either copy *or* paste?  I think the RGB triplets should not be touched, and the monitor profile should be used for display only should it not?  This is how Windows itself works which is why Print Screen doesn't change anything, copy or paste.

Comment: Should this question be tagged as a Windows problem? I can't reproduce it on OS X. After making six copies of a bitmapped gradient I see no degradation.

Comment: Okay. Well, all I can say is that I was able to set it as a monitor profile on my computer, so maybe something is different about yours, or I did it a different way than you did. I don't have either *Mathematica* 10 or Windows 7 to hand at the moment, so I can't really comment any further on that. As for the reason why, I don't know. It is probably due to copying in DIB format on Windows, whereas other platforms may use a different approach that does not involve color profiles, or does it differently so as not to expose the bug.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I cannot reproduce this in version 9.0.0.0 on Windows Vista. So, perhaps, VIsta is still ok.

Comment: I should note I checked this on win 8.1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As I already noted above, copying a *bitmap* using keyboard copy-and-paste does not change the bitmap. This only happens when you use the copy-as-bitmap menu. So what workaround are you actually looking for? Or is the problem that *non-bitmap graphics* change colors when copied that way (I didn't test that)?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I expect to be able to select any object or group of objects in the Front End and use **Copy As Bitmap** to make a verbatim bitmap copy.  `Image`, `Raster`, `Graphics`, or otherwise.  I do not expect that operation to change my colors.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would expect that too, but since your question seems to be about bitmaps specifically the **workaround you asked for** would be simply keyboard copy 'n paste, wouldn't it? I checked ImageData of the bitmap I used and it doesn't change under that operation.

Comment: BTW shouldn't  we tag this with the "bugs" tag?

Comment: @Sjoerd I was waiting for support of that position.  I suppose here is a slight chance this is intentional?

Comment: Given that it's neither there on OSX  nor on Vista suggest to me it is unintended.

Comment: I can't tell at first but this seems to be related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26105/clipboard-with-transparency

Comment: @Oleksandr Please check updated version of my answer. Do you observe the same behavior on Windows 10?

Comment: @Alexey I'm sorry, I don't have Windows 10 yet (I didn't update my laptop so far). I only have 2003, 7, and 8.1.

Comment: @Oleksandr It was my mistake: from your [first comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92578/color-degrades-when-using-copy-as-bitmap#comment251764_92578) I assumed you have. But what about Windows 2003 and 8.1? It seems for me that the fundamental bug I describe in the UPDATE section is purely a bug in the FrontEnd and it should be present on any version of Windows (and is present in all MMa versions I checked). It also seems to be unrelated to Windows color management (unlike the original bug).

Comment: @Alexey I will try this later (if I'm not too drunk--it's my birthday today). At the moment I am in the office and only have Windows 7, which I assume won't be useful to you. Note that *Mathematica* 10 can't run on Windows 2003.

Comment: @Oleksandr Happy birthday! :) Since I observe similar behavior with all tested MMa versions, v.9 or 8 on Win2003 is sufficient.

Comment: @Oleksandr Happy Birthday from me as well. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### UPDATE from 06.11.2015

Since writing the original answer I installed updates for my Windows 7 x64. Now the original bug isn't there anymore but there still persists more fundamental bug which I observe in versions 8.0.4, 9.0.1, 10.0.1, 10.2 and 10.3 installed on the same system. This bug becomes evident when you look at the plots of horizontal channel intensity values generated by the code in the original answer. Below is output from version 10.3:

> [image: output]

---

### Original answer

I'm also on Windows 7 x64 and observe the same problem with *Mathematica* 10.2.

Here is a demonstration of what happens on the level of channel values. It supports [Oleksandr's supposition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92578/color-degrades-when-using-copy-as-bitmap/94074#comment251769_92578) that we have a color management issue here.

In a new Notebook I generate an image:

```
Image[ConstantArray[Range[0, 1, .001], {40}]]
```

> [image]

Then I programmatically copy it as Bitmap, paste below the original and save the clipboard content in `lst` (the following code should be evaluated in a `Cell` placed after the output generated by the above code):

```
lst = Table[SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, EvaluationCell];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, CellContents];
   FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "CopySpecial", "MGF"];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell, 1];
   FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "Paste"];
   NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]], {20}];
```

Here is how my Notebook looks afterwards:

[image: screenshot]

Now I extract horizontal channel values for successive images and plot them separately for every channel:

```
channelData = 
  ImageData[ToExpression[#[[1, 1, 1, 1]]], Automatic, Interleaving -> False][[All, 
      20]] & /@ lst;
Column[ListLinePlot[channelData[[All, #]], PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> {"Red", "Green", "Blue"}[[#]], ImageSize -> 700] & /@ {1, 2, 3}]
```

> [image: plots]

Indeed it looks like some color transformation is applied to image when you copy it as Bitmap which results in color degradation mainly due to clipping off color values after conversion and also due to rounding off errors.

I suppose that the FrontEnd relies upon some Windows functionality for rendering of an expression when you copy it as Bitmap. And even when what you copy is already an `Image`, FrontEnd nevertheless handles it the same way.

---

The only workaround I can suggest is do not rely upon `FrontEndToken`s for rasterization and use `Rasterize` instead. Just for completeness, [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38776/280) demonstrates why we should not rely upon `FrontEndToken`s even for exporting.

---

### Workaround

In the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92578/color-degrades-when-using-copy-as-bitmap/94074#comment254722_92578) William points to [the thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26105/280) which contains `.NET`-based solution allowing to copy graphics into clipboard already in compressed PNG format with highest quality currently [available in *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17638/280). For your particular application the [solution by Todd Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28280/280) can be modified as follows (the following respects the styles of the selected Notebook):

```
Needs["NETLink`"]

CopyAsPNG[g_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  CopyAsPNG[Rasterize[Style[g, Options[SelectedNotebook[]]], "Image", opts]];
CopyAsPNG[i_Image] := Module[{png, strm, dataObject}, InstallNET[];
  png = ExportString[i, "PNG"];
  NETBlock[strm = NETNew["System.IO.MemoryStream", ToCharacterCode[png]];
   dataObject = NETNew["System.Windows.Forms.DataObject"];
   dataObject@SetData["PNG", strm];
   LoadNETType["System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard"];
   Clipboard`SetDataObject[dataObject]]]
```

Checking:

```
ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", "Panel"] // CopyAsPNG
Paste[]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: On my system (Mathematica 10.2, Windows 10) your code just gives me 20 perfect copies of the original image.

Comment: Alexey, thank you for your analysis.  Windows somehow manages to avoid this problem when using **Print Screen** so clearly it is possible.  Unfortunately **Print Screen** is inconvenient and has trouble when the object to copy is larger that one display space.  I appreciate your reminder to use `Export` for e.g. `.PDF` but unfortunately neither `Export` nor `Rasterize` respect my `FontProperties -> "ScreenResolution"` setting so I again have trouble.

Comment: @Simon I think one needs to have a calibration profile loaded to see this effect.

Comment: @Simon I am trying to pin down the exact combination of factors that result in this problem.  It *may* have something to do with my use of **ColorVisionStartup** but I am not sure.  Alexey, what method of display calibration are you using and how is the LUT loaded?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I didn't calibrated my monitor, it is just the defaults after Win7 installation (but I probably tuned ClearType settings). How can I find information about LUT in my system?

Comment: @Alexey That's a good question!  I don't know of a utility that lets one read the currently loaded graphics card LUT.  I know that when I launch **ColorVisionStartup** it tells me if the profile is successfully loaded.  I know that when I start Windows display calibration (past the first **Next** but before any adjustments are made) it appears to unload my custom profile, then when I cancel the calibration it is automatically reloaded.  If I remember I'll look for information on reading the existing LUT.

Comment: Alexey, a software called "dispcalGUI" along with "Argyll" can do these things.  You can view the curves that are loaded, reset them, or load others.  (Apparently I am using calibration curves, not a true LUT.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have installed them but I can't figure out how to obtain useful information.

Comment: Open `dispcalGUI.exe` and go to menu **Tools** an check both **Show curves** and **Show actual calibration curves**.  That should show you what is (or isn't) loaded.  If it is a single straight white line I believe no calibration is loaded.  Try also menu **Options** > **Load calibration curves from the current display device profile** and **Options** > **Reset video card gamma table**.  On my system this works correctly, meaning I see both the change in on-screen color and the updating of the curves window.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard There is no menu item "Show actual calibration curves" in the **Tools** menu but in the "Curves" window I checked the option **Show calibration curves from video card**. With this option I see the straight line, without it I see no line at all. Other options you mention change nothing.