# How to properly copy an image from Mathematica?

Tags: export, image, windows, clipboard

I want to copy an image in mathematica to use in another program.

E.g:

```
im = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]
```

[image]

When I evaluate `im // CopyToClipboard` and paste in another program, the image is destroyed.

Irfanview:
[image]

Paint is similar just slightly brighter:
[image]

I know I can export as the image .png and get the right thing. It also works using print screen followed by cropping in the target program. Is there no way to make it work correctly by simple using the clipboard?

I'm using V11.3 on Windows.

Comment: Can you describe 'destroyed' a little more, you don't describe the images you're showing so I don't know what I'm supposed to take from them. Is only the red square copied? Do you not like the artifacts? On my Mac I can open the copied image up in Preview and it looks fine - might be an OS issue.

Comment: Are you aware that you can simply select the image (just click on it], then copy-paste it in another program (control-C  control-V on windows)

Comment: @N.J.Evans `ImageDimensions[im]` is `{256, 256}`, but when I evaluate `im // CopyToClipboard` and paste in paint, the dimension change to `{256, 255}`, a margin of white pixels appears, and artifacts are introduced all over the image pixels. In free clipboard viewer 3.0 for windows, the artifacts appears too.

Comment: @andre Yes, but when using those short cuts the behavior is the exact same as that of `im // CopyToClipboard`.

Comment: @MeMyselfI , ok, I don't see those artifacts, or a margin. Dimensions look good too, I'm guessing it's a windows problem. You might submit a bug report to Wolfram. Someone here might have a workaround.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Color degrades when using Copy As Bitmap](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92578/280)." Check the "Workaround" section in the accepted answer.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you for that link, but unfortunately when using that workaround function to copy an image, I can only paste in Mathematica. However, I have found solution now.

Comment: @MeMyselfI Actually you can also paste in MS Word, Excel, PowerPoint and other applications which support importing the PNG file format from clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading and extracting http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd-x64.zip makes the function

```
copy = (Export["C:\\nircmd\\asd.png", #];
    RunProcess[{"C:\\nircmd\\nircmdc.exe",
                "clipboard", "copyimage", "\"C:\\nircmd\\asd.png\""}];) &;
```

copy images from mathematica (as well as everything that exports properly as PNG), and I get the same correct result when pasting in all my programs.

When using `RunProcess` no console window pops up unlike when `Run` is used.

**Update:** It is better to combine the code above with that of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48390/47990).
I.e let the file `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload/FrontEnd/init.m` contain

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands["Copy", {MenuItem["Copy Image",
 FrontEndExecute[Module[{}, FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["Copy"]];
  RunProcess[{"C:\\nircmd\\nircmdc.exe", "clipboard", "copyimage",
   "\"" <> Export["C:\\nircmd\\asd.png", NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]]] <> "\""}];]],
 MenuKey["c", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Command"}],
   System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"]}]]
```

which makes <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> copy images correctly.