# Copying Bitmaps in 13.1.0.0

Tags: plotting, interoperability

I have just installed 13.1.0.0 and have been copying bitmaps (`ListLinePlot`) from notebooks (Edit->CopyAs->Bitmap) into various MS applications in Windows 10. PowerPoint and Word are OK, but Visio shows only a blank frame.

```
SetOptions[ListLinePlot, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Gill Sans MT", FontSize -> 14}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold], ImageSize -> 500, ImageMargins -> 20];
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000], PlotStyle -> Black]
```

Will report as a bug if confirmed.

Comment: This is presumably in Windows (10?)?

Comment: Yes it is Windows 10

Comment: Next time, information like that should be included in the question, more so that you're using *Mathematica* with other software.

Comment: Using Paste Special > Bitmap in Visio 2021 appears to work just fine.  The "Device Independent Bitmap" format does not work in Visio.  However, both Word and PowerPoint appear to work using that format.  So, it looks more like a bug in Visio at the moment.

Comment: Maybe as a workaround try https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185455

Comment: For a workaround, I simply copy into PowerPoint and then cut/paste into Visio. That works without issue. FYI: This copy functionality was working in Mathematica 12.XXX with the same version of Visio Version 2205 Build 16.0.15225.20028 32-bit.