# Plot Command With Clean Grid Lines

Tags: plotting

I am trying to emulate this plot using Mathematica.

[image]

Using the following command, I cannot get the grid points correct.

```
  Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -4, 4}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> {{Black, Blue}, {Red, Green}}, 
   GridLines -> {Range[-4, 4], Range[-25, 25]}]
```

This results in:

[image]

Is there something that can be done to get it to look like the first plot (which was done using Microsoft Equation)?

Comment: You can use the third argument of `Range` to control the distance between gridlines and you can use `GridLinesStyle` to control their appearance.

Comment: For the internal ticks [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/labels-and-tickmarks-inside-frame) may be of help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all you need to do is make the gridlines look better, just change your plot command to have these options `GridLines -> {Range[-4, 4, .5], Range[-32, 32, 4]},GridLinesStyle -> LightGray`.  But if you want to fully reproduce that plot, see below.

Something like this is not an exact reproduction

```
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -4, 4},
 PlotRange -> {-33, 33},
 Frame -> True,
 Ticks -> {LinTicks, LinTicks},
 FrameTicks -> All,
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Black, Blue}, {Red, Green}},
 GridLines -> {Range[-4, 4, .5], Range[-32, 32, 4]},
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
 ImageSize -> 600,
 FrameStyle -> ColorData[97][1],
 AxesStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][1], Arrowheads[0.03]]]
```

[image]

But man, would be nice if we could have tick marks on the axes as well as on the frame.  According to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44604/9490) this is impossible without using `Overlay` (and I hate using `Overlay`).  There is a neat solution using `extraAxisPlot` from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103382/9490)

```
baseplot = Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -4, 4},
   PlotRange -> {-33, 33},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> All,
   FrameTicksStyle -> {{Black, Blue}, {Red, Green}},
   GridLines -> {Range[-4, 4, .5], Range[-32, 32, 4]},
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   FrameStyle -> ColorData[97][1],
   Axes -> False];

extraAxisPlot[baseplot, {{-3.8, -30}, {3.8, 30}}, {-3.8, -30},
 "AxisType" -> "Both",
 "AxisOptions" -> {AxesStyle -> 
    Directive[ColorData[97][1], Arrowheads[0.03]], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontOpacity -> 0}}]
```

[image]

**Edit** As Nasser says it is hard to put the tick labels inside the frame - you have to use Heike's [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2608/9490), but then that `Epilog` will override the `Epilog` that shows the axes so I need to give another option to `extraAxisPlot`

```
baseplot = Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -4.2, 4.2},
   PlotRange -> {-34, 34},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> All,
   FrameTicksStyle -> (FontOpacity -> 0),
   GridLines -> {Range[-4, 4, .5], Range[-32, 32, 4]},
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   FrameStyle -> ColorData[97][1],
   Axes -> False];

Show[extraAxisPlot[baseplot, {{-3.8, -30}, {3.8, 30}}, {-3.8, -30},
  "AxisType" -> "Both",
  "AxisOptions" -> {AxesStyle -> 
     Directive[ColorData[97][1], Arrowheads[0.03]], 
    LabelStyle -> {FontOpacity -> 0}}, 
  "ExtraEpilog" -> {Table[
     Text[i, {i, -34}, {0, -1}, BaseStyle -> ColorData[97][1]], {i, 
      Range[-4, 4, 2]}],
    Table[
     Text[i, {i, 34}, {0, 1}, BaseStyle -> ColorData[97][1]], {i, 
      Range[-4, 4, 2]}],
    Table[
     Text[i, {-4.2, i}, {-.5, 0}, BaseStyle -> ColorData[97][1]], {i, 
      Range[-30, 30, 10]}],
    Table[
     Text[i, {4.2, i}, {.5, 0}, BaseStyle -> ColorData[97][1]], {i, 
      Range[-30, 30, 10]}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

maybe this is a start. Putting the ticks inside is kind'a hard.  (ps. the yellow background, is from Mathematica itself. I have to accept yellow color in place of pausing when opening any new notebook or window. So I took the yellow color. Mathematica graphic card bug on windows)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
glx = Table[
   If [Mod[i, 2] == 
     0, {i, {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}}, {i, {Thin, Blue}}], {i, -4, 4, .5}];
gly = Table[
   If [Mod[i, 16] == 
     0, {i, {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}}, {i, {Thin, Blue}}], {i, -32, 32, 4}];
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3}, {x, -4, 4},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicksStyle -> Blue,
 GridLines -> {glx, gly},
 PlotRange -> {{-4.5, 4.5}, {-36, 36}},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Axes -> False,
 Epilog -> {
   {Thick, Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{-3, 0}, {3, 0}}]},
   {Thick, Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{0, -30}, {0, 30}}]},
   Text[Style[Style["y"], Italic], {-.1, 28}], 
   Text[Style["x", Italic], {3, -2}]
   },
 PlotStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"},
 FrameTicks -> {{Range[-32, 32, 16], Range[-32, 32, 16]}, {Range[-4, 4, 2], 
    Range[-4, 4, 2]}}
 ]
```

Comment: Could this be related to your yellow tint? [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87072/my-mathematica-has-turned-orange-and-not-able-to-find-out-why/87076#87076)

Comment: @AxelF exactly. After making that "fix" in the question there, my Mathematica got inflicted with the dreaded `Formatting Notebook Contents` problem each time I open any new notebook or do anything. So I removed the graphic card update and went back to the yellow Mathematica, but now without having to suffer with `Formatting Notebook Contents`. 10.3.1 on windows 7, 64 bit.